# Loop over pixel data using Python in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.0

Further to my [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136637/validate-existance-of-rgb-channels) I'm trying to check the validity of bitmaps. Mainly for transparent or black pixels.

I'm new to ArcMap, and I now know that Python scripts can be run from Arc.

Any hoops, the following script loops over the bitmap pixel by pixel using Pillow.

```
# get image (theFile) & threshold (th)
f = theFile
img = Image.open(theFile)

w = img.size[0]
h = img.size[1]

pix = img.load()


blackCount = 0
for y in range(h):
  for x in range(w):
    p = pix[x,y]
    r,g,b, a = p

    print ("r, g, b: %s, %s, %s" % (r, g, b))

    if (r <= th) & (g <= th) & (b <= th):
      blackCount +=1
```

However, I realised that Pillow can't handle large bitmap files (I'm looking at images in excess of 2GB)

What's the best way to achieve this through ArcMap?

Bearing in mind I need to look over hundreds of directories containing each tiff. The results just need to be in the form of a text file - damage to each bitmap(s) (number of pixels effected) and the name of the file(s) in question.

Comment: Have you looked into ArcPy?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Find  black & transparent pixels in large tiff files

Comment: Have you looked into [converting the raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm) into [numpy arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)?

Answer (score 2):

I would go as @crmackev suggest. Get the rasters into numpy arrays. Here you have some basic code to do that: How to get your raster in Numpy and get cell's value.

```
  # Dem_Raster to array
  # This will get the raster info into a Numpy array (m cols by n rows)
  array_dem = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(source_dem, nodata_to_value=-99999)
  #This will get you the number of rows and columns in your array
  (max_rows, max_cols) = array_dem.shape

  # Loop thru all the cells in array
  for m in max_rows:
      for n in max_cols:
          cell_value = array_dem.item(m,n)
          # do your process here...
          if cell_value = black   # this is not python, its pseudocode
             black_count += 1
       print black_count.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd warn that this will have the same issue as Pillow - running out of memory when the array read is too large. So you'll really want to write a loop and read windows of your raster into the array using the `lower_left_corner`, `nrows` and `ncols` arguments as well.